# Explicitly declare defaulted methods in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, default, delete-operator, code-structure

According to C++11 standard you can declare special member functions as defaulted using `default` keyword.

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo& source) = default;
    Foo(Foo&& source) = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& right) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&& right) = default;
};
```

I was wondering is it a good practice to declare all those methods explicitly defaulted or deleted if you don't need custom implementation of them. For example, I need to implement copy constructor and copy-assignment operator for my class. Should I mark all other special member function with `default` or `delete` keywords in order to not think each time I look at a class which are provided by compiler and which are not?

Comment: IMO, it's pure noise: it doesn't add anything to what the (good) C++ programmer already knows.

Comment: @Park Young-Bae could you make it an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. There are rules to when and whether the compiler will generate those functions automatically. In cases when the compiler wont do that and you need them, you could force it to generate them by using default or implement it yourself. The cases when the compiler wont generate functions are (this is not the full list, please refer to you're compiler's documentation):

- no default constructor is generated when a constructor with arguments is declared
- no move constructor and move assignment operator is generated when you declare copy constructor and copy assignment operator (and visa-versa)

So, in those cases you might want to bring them back by using `default` if you know that they'll be needed somewhere. In most cases, however, you should let the compiler do its thing. You'll get an error if one of those functions is not implemented automatically.

P.S. Visual studio does not yet support `default` and `delete` for move constructor and move assignment operator, yet.

Comment: I think OP knows this. He is asking whether it is good practice to default or delete these methods when there is strictly no need to do so.

Comment: @rashmatash thanks for your answer, but juanchopanza is absolutely precise with his assumption. I do aware of methods creation conditions and interested in whether it's a good practice to declare them when I do not really need them

Comment: Also, it isn't the compiler who decides. The rules are laid out in the language specification.